# Charts - How to set "using first column as labels" in google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

In google sheets, chart editor we have an option to "Use first column as label". What is the syntax to set this option in google script ?

Comment: It depends, how far have you gotten?

Comment: Could you add more details of what type of chart are you using or a sample chart to refer to?